# specified cast is not valid in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I used this code:

```
int i = Int32.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[rowID].Cells["ProfID"].Value.ToString());
var db = new bouDataDataContext();
var sel = db.Payments.Where(c => c.WTID == wtID && c.ProfID == i).Single();
```

and  `c.WTID`  is defined as integer in the database but I receive this error:

> specified Cast is not a valid

Comment: What are the type of WTID and ProfID defined in the Payments class?

Comment: WTID and ProfID defined in database as int type

Comment: @HadiKhodayari I was asking you the types defined in Payment class.

Comment: I assume the error is on the third line? If so, there is no reason why this exception would occur in your code, is there more code involved?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because you are doing

```
c.ProfID == i
```

where c.ProfID is a string, and i is an integer, if not then

```
var sel = db.Payments.Where(c => c.WTID == (int)wtID && c.ProfID == i).Single();
```

should work, that is, if `wtID` can be casted to integer

Comment: If an implicit cast does not work - how should an explicit one?